# Copy from one table to another and replace with SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I'm denormalizing an existing database by moving all physical address columns to a dedicated Address table, like so:

#### Old:

```
Customers (CustomerId, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Country, etc )
Employees (EmployeeId, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Country, etc )
Orders (OrderId, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Country, etc )
```

#### New:

```
Addresses (AddressId, Street, City, State, Country, Zip )
Customers (CustomerId, AddressId, etc )
Employees (CustomerId, AddressId, etc )
Orders (CustomerId, AddressId, etc )
```

Getting data from each table into Addresses is easy enough:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (Street, City, State, Country)
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(AddressLine1, AddressLine2), City, State, Country) 
    FROM Customers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(AddressLine1, AddressLine2), City, State, Country) 
    FROM Employees
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       CONCAT(AddressLine1, AddressLine2), City, State, Country) 
    FROM Orders
```

But how can I get the new `AddressId` value for each inserted row and set it as the `Customers.AddressId`, `Employees.AddressId`, and `Orders.AddressId` values?

...ideally without using a giant loop that gets a single row, inserts it, and updates with `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that

1) Adresses, Customers, Employees and Orders have the following PKs: AdressId, CustomerId, EmployeeId, OrderId

and

2) The dbo.Adresses.AdressId column (PK) has the IDENTITY property

then for every source table (Customers, etc.) you could use following approach:

```
/*
-- Just once
CREATE TABLE #AffectedRows (
    SourceID    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AdressID    INT NOT NULL
)
*/
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRAN
TRUNCATE TABLE #AffectedRows

MERGE dbo.Adresses a
USING dbo.Customers c ON a.AdressID = c.AdressID
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT (City)
    VALUES (c.City)
OUTPUT c.CustomerId, inserted.AdressId INTO #AffectedRows;

UPDATE  c
SET     c.AdressId = ar.AdressId
FROM    dbo.Customers c
JOIN    #AffectedRows ar ON c.CustomerId = ar.SourceId
--WHERE c.AdressId IS NULL
COMMIT

SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers
```

Comment: This is a basic approach. If you want to remove addresses which are duplicated then  let me know. Also, if there is no IDENTITY property defined on dbo.Adresses.AdressId PK let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `CURSOR` approach that works, though it isn't particularly fast, and it needs to be replicated for each table I'm reading from:

```
DECLARE @customerId int, @address1 nvarchar(200), @address2 nvarchar(200), @addressCity nvarchar(100), @addressState nvarchar(50), @addressZip nvarchar(50)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        CustomerId,
        AddressLine1,
        AddressLine2,
        AddressCity,
        AddressState,
        AddressZip
    FROM
        Customers
    WHERE
        LEN( AddressLine1 ) > 0 OR
        LEN( AddressLine2 ) > 0 OR
        LEN( AddressCity ) > 0 OR
        LEN( AddressState ) > 0 OR
        LEN( AddressZip ) > 0

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @customerId, @address1, @address2, @addressCity, @addressState, @addressZip

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Addresses ( Street, City, State, PostalCode, Country )
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN LEN( @address2 ) > 0 THEN CONCAT( @address1, CHAR(13), CHAR(14), @address2 ) ELSE @address1 END,
        @addressCity,
        @addressState,
        @addressZip,
        'United States'

    UPDATE Customers SET AddressId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE CustomerId = @customerId

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @customerId

END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE C
```

I had previously only stored the `@customerId` as a variable and did `SELECT (addressCols) FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @customerId` but performance was even worse (the table has all the necessary indexes - so it's probably just because it was doing an unnecessary extra read).

I'd love to see if there's a better approach than this.